# Checkbox disappears when spinner item is selected in Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-support-library, android-xml, android-support-design

I have a fragment in which I have a spinner and checkbox.

The layout file **need_help_fragment_layout.xml**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/all_fragment_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/parent_top"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/parent_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/parent_left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0"/>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/parent_right"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/top_title_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".25"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/top_title_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/parent_right"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/parent_left"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/parent_top">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_top"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.07"/>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_view_right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".93"/>
        <TextView
            android:text="@string/need_help_header_text"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/title_header_text_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/text_view_top"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/text_view_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/text_view_left"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/text_view_right"
            android:textColor="@color/all_text_color"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:gravity="center">
        </TextView>
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:id="@+id/mid_content_bottom_guide"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".8"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/top_title_bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mid_content_bottom_guide"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/parent_left"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/parent_right">
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/mid_content_top"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/mid_content_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/mid_content_left"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".07"/>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/mid_content_right"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".93"/>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".2"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
            android:background="@null"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/mid_content_top"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/spinner_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mid_content_left"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mid_content_right"
            android:id="@+id/spinner_view"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal | bottom"
            android:text="3 Seconds"
            android:textColor="@color/all_text_color"
            android:textSize="22sp" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_top"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".4"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/checkbox_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".6"
            android:orientation="horizontal"/>
        <CheckBox
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:text="Remove timing, Auto Mode"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/checkbox_top"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/checkbox_bottom"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/mid_content_left"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/mid_content_right"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@color/all_text_color"
            android:id="@+id/remove_timing_auto_mode_check_box"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Code in fragment:

```
class NeedHelpFragment: Fragment(), View.OnClickListener {
    lateinit var homeActivity : MainActivity
    var check_box: CheckBox? = null
    var spinner_view: Spinner? = null
    lateinit var timeSpinnerList: ArrayList<String>
    lateinit var timeSpinnerAdapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        if(context is MainActivity)
            homeActivity = context
    }
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        var v : View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.need_help_fragment_layout, container, false)
        check_box = v.findViewById<CheckBox>(R.id.check_box)
        timeSpinnerList = ArrayList()
        for(i in 0..10)
            timeSpinnerList.add("$i seconds")
        timeSpinnerAdapter = ArrayAdapter(homeActivity, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, timeSpinnerList)
        spinner_view = v.findViewById<Spinner>(R.id.spinner_view)
        spinner_view!!.adapter = timeSpinnerAdapter
        return v
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    }

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        when(view!!.id){

        }
    }
}
```

The color code:

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#6200EE</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#3700B3</color>
<color name="colorAccent">#03DAC5</color>
<color name="all_text_color">#6F6F6F</color>
<color name="all_fragment_background">#F8F8F8</color>
```

**When anything is not selected it is fine**:

[image: When anything is not selected it is fine]

**When an item is selected from the spinner, the checkbox disappears**:

[image: When an item is selected from the spinner, the checkbox disappears]

There is nothing else in the layout file. Just the constraint layout and the guidelines for the checkbox and spinner. The spinner and the checkbox are initialized in the onCreateView of the fragment. The checkbox disappears when I select any item from the spinner. Please help.

Comment: Push your XML codes completely.

Comment: I have the same issue, check you accent color ;) It seems to be white

Comment: Push your XML  and Fragment codes completely

Comment: @mohosyny Done. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @miladsalimi Done. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @Vlad It's not white.

Comment: Import `need_help_fragment_layout` XML codes too!!

Comment: @miladsalimi The layout code is of "need_help_fragment_layout.xml" code only. I have edited the question. Please have a look at it.

Comment: @AnandVardhan , Does my answer work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the **problem** is about your setting value about `constraintLayout` options like :

```
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_view"
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
```

I think that was **wrong** in some cases.

Then for simple example i removed **guidelines** and i solved it.

You can use this **approach** and add your guidelines.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/all_fragment_background"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:focusable="true">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title_header_text_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="HEAD"
        android:textColor="@color/all_text_color"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:text="3 Seconds"
        android:textColor="@color/all_text_color"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/remove_timing_auto_mode_check_box"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/title_header_text_view" />


    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/remove_timing_auto_mode_check_box"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layoutDirection="rtl"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Remove timing, Auto Mode"
        android:textColor="@color/all_text_color"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/spinner_view" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```